# In-app purchase of credits to be used in external website?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I'm thinking of implementing in-app purchases for my iphone app. My question is whether or not I can implement a credit system. I'd like to allow users of the app to purchase various quantities of credits. The credits would then be stored in a DB for that user's account. The user can then visit a dedicated website for the app and use the credits they've purchased through the app to buy various products and merchandise, etc. Will Apple allow this type of in-app purchase or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: They won't allow that. They specifically say that you can't use in-app purchases to purchase 'credits' or 'money equivalents'. Also, you can only use in-app purchases to purchase content and features specifically for the app itself, and not for any other type of merchandise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not allowed, have a look at the [App store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), especially section 11.

`11.3 - Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected`

`11.4 - Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the application`

Comment: That stinks. Is there another approach I could take to achieve a similar end result?